# What is the correct function pointer for an unsigned WINAPI function?

Tags: c++, winapi, function-pointers

I've a function declared in this way:

```
unsigned WINAPI searchSTR(void *j);
```

And I need a pointer to this function. My idea was:

```
unsigned (*pointerF) (void*);
pointerF = &searchSTR;
```

But there is an error:

```
"1 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'
                                       to 'unsigned int (__cdecl *)(void *)' ".
```

I tried other sintax, but nothing seems correct, he doesn't like the word WINAPI.

Can you suggest me the correct syntax? Maybe it is easy but I am blocked ! Thanks to all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `WINAPI` macro expands to `__stdcall`, which is a different calling convention from the default `__cdecl`. You need to mark your function pointer with the calling convention to use:

```
unsigned (WINAPI *pointerF) (void*)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 auto pointerF = &searchSTR;
```

Stop writing 1990's code. The compiler already knows the right type.

Comment: This answer is not generally applicable. The pointer can be the result of a call to [GetProcAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212.aspx), for example. Likewise, formal parameters need to be typed. And frankly, when it comes to **reading** code, I love people writing 1990's code, and don't overuse the `auto` keyword everywhere. It's meant for times, when do not know the type (e.g. template library code).

Comment: @IInspectable: the problem strarts with a (typed) function and needs a typed pointer. GetProcAddress begins with an untyped pointer. That's two major differences.

Comment: Hence the term *"not **generally** applicable"*. `auto` could be used here (although I wouldn't recommend it). `auto` cannot be used in the formal parameter list of a function, though.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys ! In my slides there is written that = &searchSTR or = searchSTR is correct, but it don't motive this sentence

Comment: @JoeMatt: There's an implicit conversion from "function type" to "pointer to function", which explains why the address operator isn't strictly necessary here. _This does not apply to objects, only to functions!_